# UIImagePicker: what file format is used when saving a movie?

Tags: ios, file, format

When I use an UIImagePicker to record video and then want to save it to disk, what file format is used? In other words.. when I have the file on disk and want to transport it over to a server, what kind if MIME type should I use?

Comment: mov file format is used in saving and retrieving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format that is used when you take a video with `UIImagePickerController` is Apple's quicktime format .MOV.

The MIME-type you are looking for is `video/quicktime`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Do you, by chance, also know the mime type for MP4/AAC files? That is, the files you can create with an AVAudioRecorder if you pass kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC as quality?

Comment: I don't have experience with that one, but a quick search on the web, said that for any AAC audio, the MIME-type should be `audio/aac`